# react native immutable data structure error

Tags: react-native

In my application, I have the following code.

```
   case ADD_MOVEMENT:
      let am_selectedTrainerMovements = state.selectedTrainerMovements;

      state.trainerMovements.forEach(movement => {
        if (movement.id === action.movement.id) {
          am_selectedTrainerMovements.push(movement);
        }
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        selectedTrainerMovements: am_selectedTrainerMovements
      };
      break;
```

In the reducer I use this case. But this gives me an error saying "the push method cannot be invoked on immutable data structure"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You set am_selectedTrainerMovements equal to state.selectedTrainerMovements and so you are just creating a new pointer to the exact same object. So when you call am_selectedTrainerMovements.push to are trying to change the state which is immutable.

You you need to clone state.selectedTrainerMovements, for instance:

```
let am_selectedTrainerMovements = 
    Object.assign({}, state. state.selectedTrainerMovements);
```